# Need help selecting tags from browser console using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, console, each

I am getting an error trying to get each tag with a certain class and only the `innerHTML` of the tag. I am trying to

```
$(".acol").innerHTML.each(function(i) {
  console.log($(this));
});
```

but getting errors as it is `passing to .each`. Can anyone help? I think it is fairly simple.

thanks!

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Cannot read property 'each' of undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.innerhtml` [returns string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) not an object so you got the error and `.each` [needs array or object](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). However, you can change your code to the below code:

```
$(".acol").each(function(i) {
  console.log($(this).html());
});
```

Comment: @user1807880 These answers all work but this explains why which sets it apart.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$.each($(".labelCol"),function(key,val){
   var innerHTML = $(val).html();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".acol").each(function(i) {
  console.log($(this).html()); 
});
```